# Grouping MongoDB Data by Ignition Field Values: A Solution for Large Datasets

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, window-functions

I want to group the data based on the values of the "ignition" field. If the "ignition" value is 1, all records with the value 1 should be grouped together until the next value of 0 is encountered, and so on.

I have 86400 records in MongoDB, and I want to query the data to achieve the desired output.

The data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    ignition: 1,
    time: 112        
  },
  {
    ignition: 1,
    time: 193        
  },     
  {
    ignition: 0,
    time: 115        
  },
  {
    ignition: 1,
    time: 116        
  },
  {
    ignition: 1,
    time: 117        
  },
  {
    ignition: 1,
    time: 118        
  },
  {
    ignition: 0,
    time: 119        
  },
  {
    ignition: 1,
    time: 120        
  },
  {
    ignition: 1,
    time: 121        
  },
  {
    ignition: 1,
    time: 122        
  },
  {
    ignition: 0,
    time: 123        
  },
]
```

I want the output like this:

```
{
  time: [112,193],
  time: [116,117,118],
  time: [120,121,122]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $setWindowFields: {                         //6. the output of this stage is, each set of adjacent documents having same $ignition will have a unique groupNum
      partitionBy: null,
      sortBy: {time: 1},                        //4. from all documents sorted by $time
      output: {
        "groupNum": {                           //1. create a new field groupNum
          $sum: {                               //2. by cumulatively adding
            $cond: [  
              {$eq: ["$ignition",1]}, 0, 1      //3. modified $ignition field
            ]
          },
          window: {
            documents: ["unbounded","current"]  //5. starting from the beginning to current document
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {"ignition": 1}                     //7. retain $ignition : 1
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$groupNum",                         //8. group by groupNum
      time: {$push: "$time"}                    //9. pushing the time to an array
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {_id: 1}                             //10.sort as necessary
  }
])
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JjKz0hxItzw)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to address my concern. However, even if I change the value of the 'time' field, the query's results do not meet my requirements. I would like the query to not depend on the 'time' field in order to obtain the desired outcome

Comment: What do you mean not depend on 'time' field? You need some sort order, without which how will you determine which documents should be grouped togather.

Comment: suppose index 0 has an 'ignition' value of 1 and a 'time' value of 10, and index 2 also has an 'ignition' value of 1 and a 'time' value of 23. However, index 3 has an 'ignition' value of 0. In this case, the desired output should be 'time': [10, 23] but your query given me different output

Comment: You can remove the sort field. `sortBy: {}`
https://mongoplayground.net/p/2POcWyZnxAM
But, this may not guarantee same result everytime.